# Error inflating class ImageView Resources$NotFoundException invalid drawable tag vector

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I am getting below exception in some devices-

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class ImageView
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
       at 
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_folder_red_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f0800a2
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3066)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.addContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
      Caused by org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:986)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:930)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3062)
       at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
       at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.addContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:690)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
```

My drawable is placed in src->main->res->drawable folder and layout is in src->main->res->layout folder.
Below is drawable and layout files-

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/folderImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_red_24dp" />
```

drawable

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:pathData="M10,4H4c-1.1,0 -1.99,0.9 -1.99,2L2,18c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h16c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V8c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2h-8l-2,-2z"/>
</vector>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing

```
android:src="@drawable/ic_folder_red_24dp"
```

to

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_folder_red_24dp"
```

resolved my issue